# Elastic queries with encrypted columns in tables using symmetric keys

Tags: azure-sql-database, encryption, azure

I have elastic queries running cross-subscription for everything except tables with encryption.

Now I need to tackle tables that are encrypted.

How (if at all possible) do I open the keys on the remote server?
i.e.

> OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY my_key DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE my_cert;

Do I somehow need to bring the cert and key over to the database where I'm running the query?